# How do I receive the default value of a form control in my custom control (ControlValueAccessor)

Tags: angular

Let's say I have a form like this:

```
this.form = fb.group({
        genders: [['MALE']],
    });
```

And I've implemented my own custom form control which implements the ControlValueAccessor interface. I understand that we have the `writeValue` method, but this method is only called when using either `setValue` or `patchValue`. How do I get the default value which was set in the `FormBuilder`'s `group` method?

Comment: Try with this.form.valueChanges.subscribe((value) => console.log(value));

Comment: This is not what I need to do. I have a custom component which implements ControlValueAccesor, thus it can be used as a form control.

Comment: I agree that none of those answers can help you (us) :) I have the same question

Comment: @Christian Hi, did you find the answer for this?

Comment: In fact, `writeValue()` *is* called with the default value that was set by means of `formBuilder.group`. The question may arise how can we pass this value to the underlying control taking into account that for the first time `writeValue()` is called *before* `ngAfterViewInit()` (so we can't use the `@ViewChild` to get access to the control at this moment)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by passing a simple @Input() inside a component.

```
@Component({ selector: 'my-component', template: `....` })
export class Component extends ControlValueAccessor {
  @Input('property') property: any;
}
```

and then inside the HTML,

```
<my-component formControl="gender" [property]="value">
```

Answer (score 0):

you want to receive the default from group value , try in your component :

```
this.form.value.genders
```

Or in your .html file you can use : `{{ form.value. genders }}`

Answer (score 0):

Actually I just tried and `writeValue` is called twice but the second time it has the right value put as init value in the form object.

Answer (score 0):

I have put together a StackBlitz for you here based on [Expertus777](https://github.com/Expertus777)'s [comment on GitHub](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/14988#issuecomment-1147812991):
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-xnvlar?file=src/app/app.component.html

The secret to getting the default value to appear is using `setTimeout` in your `writeValue` method, as follows:

```js
  writeValue(value: any): void {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.value = value;
      this.cd.markForCheck(); // optional
    }, 0);
  }
```

I'm sure you could use `NgZone`, or RxJS if you prefer too.

Answer (score 0):

The problem, as noted in the comments by @IlyaLoskutov is the following:

> In fact, `writeValue()` *is* called with the default value that was
> set by means of `formBuilder.group`. The question may arise how can we
> pass this value to the underlying control taking into account that for
> the first time `writeValue()` is called before `ngAfterViewInit()` (so
> we can't use the `@ViewChild` to get access to the control at this
> moment).

The way to solve this, is by declaring your [`@ViewChild`](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChild) with `{static: true}`, to force the view query to be executed before change detection runs.

For example, for a `ViewChild` that references an element of type `ChildType`, identified by a template reference variable `#childName`:

```
export class YourComponent implements ControlValueAccessor {
    @ViewChild('childName', { static: true })
    child?: ElementRef<ChildType>;
  
    writeValue(value: any): void {
        const element = this.select?.nativeElement;
        
        if (element) element.value = String(value || '');
    }
  
    /* rest of CVA implementation omitted */
}
```

Note that using a static `ViewChild` has implications, especially when using structural directives. See the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56359504/3558960) for more information.