# How should I use the new static option for @ViewChild in Angular 8?

Tags: angular, angular8, viewchild

How should I configure the new Angular 8 view child?

```
@ViewChild('searchText', {read: ElementRef, static: false})
public searchTextInput: ElementRef;
```

vs

```
@ViewChild('searchText', {read: ElementRef, static: true})
public searchTextInput: ElementRef;
```

Which is better? When should I use `static:true` vs `static:false`?

Answer (score 392, accepted):

In most cases you will want to use `{static: false}`. Setting it like this will ensure query matches that are dependent on binding resolution (like structural directives `*ngIf, etc...`) will be found.

Example of when to use `static: false`:

```
@Component({
  template: `
    <div *ngIf="showMe" #viewMe>Am I here?</div>
    <button (click)="showMe = !showMe"></button>
  ` 
})
export class ExampleComponent {
  @ViewChild('viewMe', { static: false })
  viewMe?: ElementRef<HTMLElement>; 

  showMe = false;
}
```

The `static: false` is going to be the default fallback behaviour in Angular 9. Read more [here](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChild#description) and [here](https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/28810)

The `{ static: true }` option was introduced to support creating embedded views on the fly. When you are creating a view dynamically and want to acces the `TemplateRef`, you won't be able to do so in `ngAfterViewInit` as it will cause a `ExpressionHasChangedAfterChecked` error. Setting the static flag to true will create your view in ngOnInit.

Nevertheless:

> In most other cases, the best practice is to use `{static: false}`.

Be aware though that the `{ static: false }` option will be made default in Angular 9. Which means that setting the static flag is no longer necessary, unless you want to use the `static: true` option.

You can use the angular cli `ng update` command to automatically upgrade your current code base.

For a migration guide and even more information about this, you can check [here](https://angular.io/guide/static-query-migration) and [here](https://next.angular.io/guide/migration-dynamic-flag)

> #What is the difference between static and dynamic queries?
> The static option for @ViewChild() and @ContentChild() queries determines when the query results become available.

> With static queries (static: true), the query resolves once the view has been created, but before change detection runs. The result, though, will never be updated to reflect changes to your view, such as changes to ngIf and ngFor blocks.

> With dynamic queries (static: false), the query resolves after either ngAfterViewInit() or ngAfterContentInit() for @ViewChild() and @ContentChild() respectively. The result will be updated for changes to your view, such as changes to ngIf and ngFor blocks.

---

A nice use-case for using `static: true`, is if you are using `fromEvent` to bind to an element defined in the template. Consider the following template:

```
<div [ngStyle]="thumbStyle$ | async" #thumb></div>
```

You can then handle events on this element without the need of using subscriptions or init hooks (if you don't want to or cannot use angular event binding):

```
@Component({})
export class ThumbComponent {
  @ViewChild('thumb', { static: true })
  thumb?: ElementRef<HTMLElement>;

  readonly thumbStyle$ = defer(() => fromEvent(this.thumb, 'pointerdown').pipe(
    switchMap((startEvent) => fromEvent(document, 'pointermove', { passive: true })
    // transform to proper positioning
  ));
}
```

It is important to use `defer`. This will make sure the observable is only resolved when it's subscribed to. This will happen before the `ngAfterViewInit` gets triggered, when the `async` pipe subscribes to it. Because we are using `static: true`, the `this.thumb` is already populated.

Comment: Please update the link for angular docs (changed after release) https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChild#description

Comment: I am not able to access the instance of childView. It says undefined all the time.

Comment: Can you please provide a link about that information of removing the static option in Angular 9?

Comment: @AlexMarinov I've updated my answer to make it more clear what's going to happen in angular 9. The link about this is in the migration guide

Comment: @NesanMano I run into the same problem today, the way I solved was to set `{ static: true }`. Hope this helps

Comment: If I nest the component inside a `*ngIf`, and that block is only set to true later, how can I take the `ViewChild`?

Comment: @MinhNghĩa if you nest the entire component outside of the component's template, you can use `{ static: true }`, but if there is no direct need for having access to the ViewChild inside `ngOnInit`, you should just use the `{ static: false }`.

Comment: Angular 9 Official Documentation: https://angular.io/guide/static-query-migration

Answer (score 193):

So as a rule of thumb you can go for the following:

- `{ static: true }` needs to be set when you want to access the `ViewChild` in `ngOnInit`.
- `{ static: false }` can only be accessed  in `ngAfterViewInit`. This is also what you want to go for when you have a structural directive (i.e. `*ngIf`) on your element in your template.

Comment: Note: In Angular 9, the static flag defaults to false, so "any {static: false} flags can be safely removed". Documentation: https://angular.io/guide/static-query-migration

Answer (score 27):

static property informs angular about the availability of our child

For example: if static is set to **true**, we are informing angular our child is available on the page from the beginning  ( meaning it is not dependent of *ngIf,page bindings,API calls etc) so angular looks for it at the earliest lifecycle hook ( ngOnInit) and never looks for it again

In case we set static to **false** we are informing angular that our child is dependent on some conditional directives, so angular tries to look for our child after every change detection cycle and if it is available we can access it in ngAfterViewInit() life cycle hook

Comment: is just the opposite manner: {static: true} Angular only check one time (At very early stage of the component -this is the reason you can get it in ngOnInit-) and the element can **not** be under a *ngIf, etc.

Comment: This was the clearest explanation for me. Thank you.

Answer (score 23):

From the angular [docs](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChild#description)

> **static** - whether or not to resolve query results before change detection runs (i.e. return static results only). If this option is not provided, the compiler will fall back to its default behavior, which is to use query results to determine the timing of query resolution. If any query results are inside a nested view (e.g. *ngIf), the query will be resolved after change detection runs. Otherwise, it will be resolved before change detection runs.

It may be a better idea to use `static:true` if the child does not depend on any conditions. If the visibility of element changes, then `static:false` may give better results.

PS: Since its a new feature, we may need to run benchmarks for performance.

### Edit

As mentioned by @Massimiliano Sartoretto , [github commit](https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/28810) may give you more insights.

Comment: I would add the official motivations behind this feature https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/28810

Answer (score 3):

Came here because a ViewChild was null in ngOnInit after upgrading to Angular 8.

Static queries are filled before ngOnInit, while dynamic queries (static: false) are filled after. In other words, if a viewchild is now null in ngOnInit after you set static: false, you should consider changing to static: true or move code to ngAfterViewInit.

See https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/core/src/view/view.ts#L332-L336

The other answers are correct and explain why this is the case: Queries dependant on structural directives, e.g. a ViewChild reference inside an ngIf, should run after the conditional of this directive has been resolved, ie after change detection. However, one may safely use static: true and thus resolve the queries before ngOnInit for unnested references. Imho this particular case bears mentioning as a null exception could likely be the first way you'll encounter this particularity, as it was for me.

Answer (score 3):

In ng8 , you can manually set when to access the child component in the parent component.
When you set static to true, it means the parent component only get the definition of the component in the `onInit` hook:
Eg:

```
 // You got a childComponent which has a ngIf/for tag
ngOnInit(){
  console.log(this.childComponent);
}

ngAfterViewInit(){
  console.log(this.childComponent);
}
```

If static is false , then you only get the defination in the ngAfterViewInit(), in ngOnInit(), you'll get undefined.

Answer (score 2):

view child @angular 5+ token two arguments ('local reference name',static: false|true)

```
@ViewChild('nameInput', { static: false }) nameInputRef: ElementRef;
```

to know the difference between true and false check this

> static - whether or not to resolve query results before change detection runs (i.e. return static results only). If this option is not provided, the compiler will fall back to its default behavior, which is to use query results to determine the timing of query resolution. If any query results are inside a nested view (e.g. *ngIf), the query will be resolved after change detection runs. Otherwise, it will be resolved before change detection runs.

Answer (score 2):

View child

... Can use it for template element reference.

...for outside of particular component reference.

With decorator style syntax..
`@ViewChild( selector) reference : ElementRef || QueryList.`

Of specific component or element reference.

Use it in `AfterViewInIt()`.

We could use it in `Oninit()`.

But this for specific to use `ngAfterViewInit()`.

Lastly `{static : false}` should be placed in `@ViewChild( Useme , { static : false})`... for template variable reference.

The variable in template file looks like.
`#Useme`.

Answer (score 0):

if we declare static: true, it will render only once at the beginning. otherwise if we declare static: false, it means that we r rendering it dynamically so whenever the changes occur it will render again and again. Its safe to declare static: false most of the time