# Angular input interpolation

Tags: angular, interpolation, angular8

I'm using this code in `my.component.ts` file:

```
// ...
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {
  user: any;
  icons = {
    search: faSearch // FontAwesome icon, it's imported
  };
  textContent = `<div class="input-group">
            <input type="text" name="search-string" placeholder="Search...">
            <div class="input-group-append">
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-default">
                <fa-icon icon="${ this.icons.search }"></fa-icon>
              </button>
            </div>
          </div>`;
// ...
```

And try to use in `my.component.html` file like this:

```
<div [innerHTML]="textContent"></div>
```

The Angular render this code:

```
<div class="input-group">
  <div class="input-group-append"></div>
</div>
```

The other codes missing... any idea why?

Comment: This appears to be going against the angular framework. So much that I would question why you're even using angular in the first place. Why are you not using angular for what it's best at (generating html for you)? Seems like a bad design.

Answer (score 1):

Did you check the console log ?
It probably has a message like:

```
WARNING: sanitizing HTML stripped some content.
```

This message means that some HTML tags were stripped for security reasons.
Using `[innerHTML]` can be a security issue.

And in this case, it is more a matter of design, imho. I would really just reccommend to put the form elements in the template file (i.e. your `my.component.html`).

Is there a specific reason why you want to put it in the `my.component.ts` file?

---

## EDIT:

From the comment section it appears that the reason for this construct is to allow developers to inject html (dynamically) inside this component.

There are a number of ways to accomplish this, one of them is content projection.

```
<my-component>
  put html in the body.
</my-component>
```

Inside the my.component.html template file you need to add a `<ng-content></ng-content>` node. The html of the body will be projected there.

So, the my.component.html could look like this:

```
<div>
  This is my component:<br>
  <ng-content></ng-content>
</div>
```

Then when you use "my component", you can do this:

```
<my-component>

  <div class="input-group">
    <input type="text" name="search-string" placeholder="Search...">
    <div class="input-group-append">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-default">
        <fa-icon icon="fa-search"></fa-icon>
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>

</my-component>
```

Optionally, you could move the inner content to a different component and do something like this:

```
<my-component>
  <my-child-component> </my-child-component>
</my-component>
```

Comment: I just wanted to put you over 9k. Plus, I agree with this comment/answer

Comment: Yes, here is a specific reason. Because this would be a multilevel navigation "constructor" where the developer can define a HTML code as dropdown menu item, like this search form.

Comment: @netdjw , I hope this additional edit points you in the right direction of a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [@ViewChild](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChild) to achieve this. The trick here is to make `static:true`, which in short skips the angular change detection cycle. You can find more on static prop from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56359504/how-should-i-use-the-new-static-option-for-viewchild-in-angular-8).

[Stackblitz Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ly5dbb)

**.html**

```
<div #dataContainer></div>
```

**.ts**

```
import { Component, ViewChild, ElementRef, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  icons = {
    search: 'faSearch'
  };
  @ViewChild('dataContainer', { static: true }) dataContainer: ElementRef;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.dataContainer.nativeElement.innerHTML = `<div class="input-group">
            <input type="text" name="search-string" placeholder="Search...">
            <div class="input-group-append">
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-default">
                 <fa-icon icon="${ this.icons.search}"></fa-icon>
              </button>
            </div>
          </div>`;
  }

}
```