# How we set focus on input element in angular7

Tags: angular, angular7

I have already imported ViewChild,ElementRef,Renderer in ts file but it's showing error of "ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'nativeElement' of undefined"

```
import { Component, OnInit,ViewChild,ElementRef,Renderer } from '@angular/core';

@ViewChild('usernameField') input : ElementRef;

this.usernameField.nativeElement.focusIn();
```

expect focus on input element.

Comment: post your html also

Comment: your variable is `this.input`, NOT this.usernameField, the function is `focus()` NOT focusIn()

Answer (score 1):

I think this will work

Instead of

```
this.usernameField.nativeElement.focusIn();
```

try

```
this.usernameField.nativeElement.focus();
```

Or else post your html so that we can see what is wrong?

Just check your input tag `#usernameField`

Like

```
<input #usernameField
```

And change your ts

```
@ViewChild('usernameField') usernameField: ElementRef;
```

Also make sure you have added focus in `ngAfterViewInit`

Like

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.usernameField.nativeElement.focus();
}
```

Comment: Html code :<input #usernameField  type="password" id="password" name="Password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password"
                    [(ngModel)]="Password" #loginpassword="ngModel"
                    [ngClass]="{'is-invalid':loginpassword.errors && loginpassword.touched}" required minlength="5">

Comment: sometime I use his trick I like to share check  https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-viewchild-static 

Comment: @malbarmawi Frankly speaking, I don't like `setTimeout` hack :(, we can't trust on it. So I avoid to use it unless it is very necessary :P

Comment: aggred  the new version angular 8 has already fixed this trick by static property

Comment: but in all cases timeout function will run after **ngAfterViewInit** 

Answer (score 0):

the `input` will be set when `ngAfterViewInit` run mean you can't use before like in  ngOnInit() method the value at that time will be `undefined`

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
 this.usernameField.nativeElement.focus();
}
```

in angular **`verion 8+`**

```
@ViewChild('usernameField',{static : true}) usernameField: ElementRef;

ngOnInit() {
 this.usernameField.nativeElement.focus();
}
```

check this  [**How should I use the new static option for @ViewChild in Angular 8?**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56359504/how-should-i-use-the-new-static-option-for-viewchild-in-angular-8)

[**check this live demo** ‍♂️‍♂️](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-viewchild-static)

Answer (score 0):

Just inject ElementRef in constructor.

`constructor(private el:ElementRef){
 this.el.nativeElement.querySelector('input[type:"text"]').focus();
}`

Comment: We can't give focus in `constructor`.... Because view is not available during constructor execution

Comment: yes. please add same line of code into ngAfterViewInit()