# How to reset the paginator?

Tags: angular, angular-material

How to reset the paginator and go to the first page? `this.page = 1` does not work correctly. Just in case, I'll explain that I do not use `MatPaginator`.

ts:

```
  pageSizeOptions = [5, 10, 25, 50, 100];
  pageSize = 5;
  page = 1;

   applyFilter() {
    let searchFilter: any = {
      filterValue: this.search
    };
    this.categories.filter = searchFilter;
    if (this.page !== 1) {
      this.page = 1;
    } else {
      this.load();
    }
  }

  onPaginateChange(event) {
    this.page = event.pageIndex + 1;
    this.pageSize = event.pageSize;
    this.load();
  }
```

html:

```
<mat-paginator [pageSizeOptions]="pageSizeOptions" [length]="totalItems" [pageSize]="pageSize"
      (page)="onPaginateChange($event)" showFirstLastButtons [disabled]="!isActive">
</mat-paginator>
```

Comment: https://jasonwatmore.com/post/2019/06/18/angular-8-simple-pagination-example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set `pageIndex` of paginator, but you will have to use `ViewChild` decorator  to select that paginator, so in your component:

```
@ViewChild(MatPaginator, {static:false}) paginator: MatPaginator;
...
```

and in your method:

```
this.paginator.pageIndex = 0;
```

Comment: `TypeError: Cannot set property 'pageIndex' of undefined`

Comment: Angular 8: `@ViewChild(MatPaginator, undefined) paginator: MatPaginator;`

Comment: @uminder thanks, i updated my answer with angular 8 viewchild

Comment: Angular 9: the { static: false } option will be made default  [@Poul Kruijt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56359504/how-should-i-use-the-new-static-option-for-viewchild-in-angular-8/56359612)

Answer (score -1):

I am using primeng. Please see below syntax to reset:

```
import { Paginator } from 'primeng/primeng';

@ViewChild('paginator') paginator: Paginator;


this.paginator.changePage(0);
```