# How to go to the 1st page of the table when searching in Angular?

Tags: typescript, angular8, mat-table, paginator

This is an angular 8 application.
It has a table with mat-paginator.

```
<mat-paginator [pageSize]="commonPageSize" [length]="totalElements"
                   (page)="getData($event.pageIndex, this.isSearch, this.key, this.value)" showFirstLastButtons></mat-paginator>
```

I get data from an API call for each **next page click**

```
(page)="getData($event.pageIndex, this.isSearch, this.key, this.value)"
```

pageSize is always 10 and I'm retrieving 10 rows per each API call. Below is my ts file.

```
  getData(pageNumber: number, isSearch: string, key: string, value: string) {
if (this.subscription) {
  this.subscription.unsubscribe();
}

this.subscription = this.service.getData(pageNumber.toString(), this.commonPageSize,
  isSearch, key, value)
  .subscribe(
    data => {
      if(data.length !== 0) {
        this.isDownloadCsvBtnEnable = false;
      }
      if(this.totalElements == null && data.length > 0) {
        this.totalElements = parseInt(data[0].totalElements,10 );
      }
      this.data= new MatTableDataSource(data);
      this.number = this.data.connect().pipe(map((data: any) => data.length === 0));
      this.data.sort = this.sort;
    }
  );
```

}

The problem is suppose I'm in the 3rd page and pass values for a search. Then table is not go to the first page. Searched data was loaded to the table for that **3rd page**. It has not navigated to the first page.. Can anyone pls tell me how to redirect to the first page.

Thnks

Comment: I found the answer in below link.. [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58004169/how-to-reset-the-paginator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58004169/how-to-reset-the-paginator)

Comment: I found the answer in below link [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58004169/how-to-reset-the-paginator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58004169/how-to-reset-the-paginator)

Answer (score 1):

There is an example of how to do this in the Angular Material docs.

https://stackblitz.com/angular/gxxgljxnpbb?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftable-overview-example.ts

Basically, you need to use ViewChild to get a reference to the paginator in the component. Then whenever the filter is changed you can tell the paginator to go to the first page.

Comment: In my case I haven't set paginator to the data set. Thank you for your answer.