# Cannot set property of undefined (when it is defined) in Angular

Tags: html, angular, typescript, timer

I am building a timer app/component and I cannot find my error. It sounds like this: Cannot set property startAt of undefined.
Don't know where is an error because I defined it in my dashboard component. Any ideas where is an error and how can I fix it? I post most of my code, maybe error is somewhere else.

This is my code:

My dashboard.ts file

```
export class DashboardComponent implements OnInit {
  appUser: User;
  clients: Client[] = [];
  today: Date = new Date(2019, 9, 25, 12, 23);     // Defualt todays time;

  @ViewChild('counter', {read: CounterComponent, static: false})
  private counter: CounterComponent;

  counterState = 'counter is ticking';
  ngOnInit() {
    this.appUser = this.userS.currentUser;
    this.clients = this.clientService.getUserClients()
    .sort((a, b) => {
      return (new Date(a.registrationDate) as any) - (new Date(b.registrationDate) as any);
    });
    this.counter.startAt = 120;   // Here I am defining it
    this.counter.counterState.subscribe((msg)=>{
      if(msg==='COMPLETE') {
        this.counterState = 'counter has stopped';
      }
    });
    this.counter.start();
  }
}
```

My dashboard.html file

```
<counter #counter></counter>
```

My Mycounter.ts file

```
@Component({
  selector: 'counter',
  templateUrl: './counter.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./counter.component.css'],
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
export class CounterComponent  {
  @Input()
  startAt:number = 1;

  @Input()
  showTimeRemaining = true;

  @Output()
  counterState = new EventEmitter();

  currentValue = '';

  private currentSubscription: Subscription;

  constructor(private changeDetector: ChangeDetectorRef) { }

  public start() {
    this.currentValue = this.formatValue(this.startAt);
    this.changeDetector.detectChanges();

    const t: Observable<number> = interval(1000);
    this.currentSubscription = t.pipe(take(this.startAt))
.pipe(  // not sure about this place but using only map but else it says 
        // Property 'map' does not exist on type 'Observable<number>'
  map(v =>    this.startAt - (v + 1))).subscribe(v => {
        this.currentValue = this.formatValue(v);
        this.changeDetector.detectChanges();
      }, err => {
        this.counterState.error(err);
      }, () => {
        this.currentSubscription.unsubscribe();
        this.currentValue = '00:00';
        this.counterState.emit('COMPLETE');
        this.changeDetector.detectChanges();
      });
  }

  private formatValue(v) {
  const minutes = Math.floor(v / 60);
          const formattedMinutes = '' + (minutes > 9 ? minutes : '0' + minutes);
          const seconds = v % 60;
          const formattedSeconds = '' + (seconds > 9 ? seconds : '0' + seconds);

  return `${formattedMinutes}:${formattedSeconds}`;
  }
}
```

Comment: Hmm, this is weird. You are defining `counter` as a `static: false` but you are trying to access it in `ngOnInit` and it is defined? That shouldn't be the case... Maybe try using `static: true` or move the "counter" code to the `ngAfterViewInit`... Actually, that is exactly the issue, `counter` is not defined and you are trying to set property `startAt` of undefined...

Comment: On what line does the error occur? If it's on the same line as the comment "Here I am defining it", then that makes perfect sense that you would get that error there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve this in 2 ways: First, you can use `static: true` to make `counter` available in `ngOnInit`:

```
@ViewChild('counter', {read: CounterComponent, static: true})
private counter: CounterComponent;
```

This way you will be able to access `counter` variable in `ngOnInit` unless there is a structural directive preventing it (like `*ngIf` for example, more on that [here](https://blog.angularindepth.com/embrace-yourself-angular-8-is-coming-1bf187c8f0bf) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56359504/how-should-i-use-the-new-static-option-for-viewchild-in-angular-8)).

The second way is to move `counter` code to `ngAfterViewInit` (there, the `counter` variable will be resolved and you won't get the error):

```
@ViewChild('counter', {read: CounterComponent, static: false})
private counter: CounterComponent;

ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.counter.startAt = 120;
    this.counter.counterState.subscribe((msg)=>{
      if(msg==='COMPLETE') {
        this.counterState = 'counter has stopped';
      }
    });
    this.counter.start();
}
```

Hope this helps...

Comment: hmm, it works, but outside ngIf which has nothing relevant with this.