# How to destroy component created dynamically angular 8

Tags: angular, angular8

I'm new to Angular. I have a button that every time I click it, it creates a component dynamically. I need each component to have a button or something that can destroy that component specifically. I have a function in the dynamic component that when I click on it, that component must be closed, but I don't know how to pass it to the function of the typescript file.Please help me.

app.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, ComponentFactoryResolver, ViewChild, Input,ComponentRef,ViewContainerRef } from '@angular/core';
import {ChatService} from "./services/chat.service";
import {Mensaje} from "./models/mensaje";
import {ConversacionComponent} from "./components/conversacion/conversacion.component";
import {ConversacionDirective} from "./components/conversacion/conversacion.directive";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
    providers:[ChatService]
})
export class AppComponent {
    @ViewChild(ConversacionDirective, {static: true}) eldinamico: ConversacionDirective;
  title = 'chat';

  constructor(private cfr: ComponentFactoryResolver){  }
    ngOnInit() { }


    componenteDinamico(mensaje: string) {
        const cf = this.cfr.resolveComponentFactory(ConversacionComponent);
        const vcr = this.eldinamico.viewContainerRef;
        vcr.createComponent(cf, 0);
    }
}
```

conversacion.directive.ts

```
import { Directive, ViewContainerRef } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
    selector: '[appConversacionDinamica]'
})
export class ConversacionDirective {

    constructor(public viewContainerRef: ViewContainerRef) { }

}
```

app.component.html

```
<input type="text" #mensaje><br/>
<button (click)="componenteDinamico(mensaje.value)"> Crear Componente </button>
<br/>
<div class="orden">
  <ng-template appConversacionDinamica></ng-template>

</div>
```

conversacion.component.html

```
<button (click)="removeObject()">delete me</button>
<div>
    this is a component dynamically
</div>
```

conversacion.component.ts

```
import {Component, Input, OnInit, Output, EventEmitter,ViewChild,ElementRef,ComponentRef} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-conversacion',
  templateUrl: './conversacion.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./conversacion.component.css']
})
export class ConversacionComponent implements OnInit {
    mensaje: string;   
    vcr:any; 

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {}   

  removeObject(){
    this.vcr.destroy();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Below is an example where the dynamic component can "delete itself". The creator (app.component.ts) subscribes to the output of the dynamic component (simple.component.ts) and then invokes `.destroy()`.

Also, the SimpleComponent has to be included in the module as an `entryComponent` since it is created dynamically.

Giphy: https://giphy.com/gifs/W2zx2dhNk4znnYFyGT

**Example:**

---

app.component.html

```html
<h1>App</h1>
<button (click)="onClickAdd()">Create</button>

<br>
<hr>
<ng-template #componentsContainer></ng-template>
```

app.component.ts

```js
import {
  Component,
  ViewChild,
  ViewContainerRef,
  ComponentFactoryResolver,
  ComponentRef,
  OnDestroy
} from '@angular/core';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';
import { tap } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { SimpleComponent } from './simple/simple.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnDestroy {
  @ViewChild('componentsContainer', { read: ViewContainerRef }) container: ViewContainerRef;
  private subs: Subscription[] = [];

  ngOnDestroy() {
    // unsubscribe from all on destroy
    this.subs.forEach(sub => sub.unsubscribe());
  }

  onClickAdd = () => {
    const factory = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(SimpleComponent);
    const component = this.container.createComponent(factory);

    component.instance.numberCreated = this.container.length;

    // subscribe to component event to know when to delete
    const selfDeleteSub = component.instance.deleteSelf
      .pipe(tap(() => component.destroy()))
      .subscribe();

    // add subscription to array for clean up
    this.subs.push(selfDeleteSub);
  }

  constructor(private componentFactoryResolver: ComponentFactoryResolver) {}
}
```

simple.component.html

```html
<button (click)="deleteSelf.emit()" style="background-color: blue; color: white">delete self</button>
<p>Dynamic Component</p>
<p>Number at time of creation: {{ numberCreated }}</p>
<hr>
```

simple.component.ts

```js
import { Component, OnInit, Output, EventEmitter, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-simple',
  templateUrl: './simple.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./simple.component.css']
})
export class SimpleComponent implements OnInit {
  @Output() deleteSelf: EventEmitter<void> = new EventEmitter<void>();
  @Input() numberCreated: number;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

app.module.ts

```js
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { SimpleComponent } from './simple/simple.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent, SimpleComponent],
  imports: [BrowserModule, AppRoutingModule],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
  entryComponents: [SimpleComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Comment: I know what do yo say,but in my scenario I don't know how to do it,could you show me please?

Comment: Hey Jesus, I updated the answer to include a working example. Let me know if it makes sense.

Comment: Its works!,but I get an error on a line, I copied exactly your code just by replacing the word SimpleComponent with ConversacionComponent and the file paths. I get an error in the line of ViewChild ."Argument of type  {read: ViewContainerRef } is not assignable to parameter of type {'read?:any;static;boolean'}Property 'static' is missing in type {read type of  ViewContainerRef } but required in type {'read?:any;static;boolean'}  "

Comment: Why show me the line of View Child like an error specifically in {read: ViewContainerRef} ?

Comment: hmm, are you importing `ViewChild` and `ViewContainerRef` from `@angular/core`?

Comment: Yes,I can't send you a picture from here. From where I could write to you so I can send you an image or file so you can see better?. Sorry for such annoyance but I'm new to Angular and I don't know anyone who can help me.

Comment: The application works as your example, but in the console I get exactly this error:
ERROR in src / app / app.component.ts (91,39): error TS2345: Argument of type '{read: typeof ViewContainerRef; } 'is not assignable to parameter of type' {read ?: any; static: boolean; } '.
       Property 'static' is missing in type '{read: typeof ViewContainerRef; } 'but required in type' {read ?: any; static: boolean; } '. I have no idea why he points out that error on the line "@ViewChild ('componentsContainer', {read: ViewContainerRef}) container: ViewContainerRef;"

Comment: Ah, Angular 8 requires the `static` field. Try this:

`@ViewChild('componentsContainer', { read: ViewContainerRef, static: false }) container: ViewContainerRef;`

Here are the docs: https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChild

And here's a link to a helpful StackOverflow answer on static `true` vs. `false`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56359612/7729975