# What is ViewChild

Tags: angular, angular5, angular8

There is declaration in component:

```
export class GlossariesComponent implements OnInit {
  @ViewChild(UploaderComponent, {static: false})
  private uploader: UploaderComponent;

}
```

Does it mean that I do reference to TEMPLATE of `UploaderComponent` component?

How then to use `@ViewChild` in current component template, now there is no place where it is used in template.

And what does mean static?

Comment: The property `uploader` will be a reference to the uploader component instance, defined inside your `GloassariesComponent` template. I don't really know what you mean with your second question. And about static i can refer you to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56359504/how-should-i-use-the-new-static-option-for-viewchild-in-angular-8/56359612#56359612)

Comment: Could you explain a main purpose of @ViewChild?

Comment: to get the reference of a component instance or the reference of a `HTMLElement` declared in your component's template

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does it mean that I do reference to TEMPLATE of UploaderComponent component?

Not quite, you will get the **instance** of that component's class.

> How then to use @ViewChild in current component template, now there is no place where it is used in template.

The purpose of `@ViewChild` is to **query** elements from your current component's **view**(template).

You can use a component in 2 ways:

- **declaratively**: by using its **selector** in a view
- **imperatively**: in simple terms, everything is done inside your class. now it is important to know about **embedded views** and **host views**(these are the components loaded imperatively)

These views must be hosted by a view container, which its job is, as its name implies, to contain multiple views.

[Read more here](https://blog.angularindepth.com/working-with-dom-in-angular-unexpected-consequences-and-optimization-techniques-682ac09f6866) about **host views, embedded views and view container**.

If you have not used the component in your template, then you shouldn't be able to grab it in your class.

> And what does mean static?

when:

- **true**

  - it is accessible in `ngOnInit()`
  - does not depend on any of `*ngIf`, `*ngFor`
- **false**

  - depends on a binding resolution(`*ngIf` etc...)
  - accessible in `ngAfterViewInit` and `ngAfterViewChecked`

You can find more details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56359504/how-should-i-use-the-new-static-option-for-viewchild-in-angular-8/56359612#56359612).

### EDIT

> why it is named as @ViewChild no @ViewCurrent

Here is my assumption:

```html
<app-root>
  <#VIEW>
    <app-child>
     <#VIEW>
       ...content goes here...
     </#VIEW>
    </app-child>
  <#VIEW>
</app-root>
```

*Snippet taken from [here](https://angular.io/guide/hierarchical-dependency-injection#logical-structure-of-the-template)*

Now, imagine you want to query for `app-child`

#### root.component.ts

```js
@Component({ /* ... */ })
export class RootComponent {
 @ViewChild(AppChild, { static: false })
 private appChild: AppChild;
}
```

A **TLDR** would be: every element(DOM element or component) in a component's view is technically a child of that component.

Comment: Excellent, but why it is named as `@ViewChild` no `@ViewCurrent` :)

Answer (score 1):

When you Want to get access to a child component, directive or a DOM element from a parent component class, It’s easy to do with the ViewChild decorator. ViewChild returns the first element that matches a given component, directive or template reference selector. In cases where you’d want to access multiple children, you’d use ViewChildren instead.[Check this for detailed explanation](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChild)