# Close mat-sidebar by eventEmmiter()

Tags: angular, angular-material

I use `material-sidebar` for showing the mobile menu.
I want to close sidebar when any of item in the menu is clicked.

I send out by the `EventEmmiter()` function to close the sidebar from child to parent controller.

```
public onSidenavClose = () => {
        this.sidenavClose.emit();
    };
```

And here in app.component.html I set like this

```
<mat-sidenav-container fxFlexFill>
    <mat-sidenav #sidenav (sidenavClose)="sidenav.close()">
      <mat-nav-list>
        <app-nav-item></app-nav-item>
      </mat-nav-list>
    </mat-sidenav>
    <mat-sidenav-content fxFlexFill>Main content</mat-sidenav-content>
  </mat-sidenav-container>
```

But can not get to close sidebar... some solution?

[Here is full working example.](https://stackblitz.com/edit/responsive-menu-angular-material-flex-layout-frxksg?file=src/app/nav-item/nav-list/nav-list.component.ts) You need to resize opened preview in stackblitz to get the mobile nav.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You added Event emitter to wrong element, add `(sidenavClose)="sidenav.close()"` to app-nav-item

```
<app-nav-item (sidenavClose)="sidenav.close()"></app-nav-item>
```

**EDIT**
Your event emitter is on grand child which is `<app-nav-list>`, @output/Event Emitter is for direct parent, To make this work create a shared service to communicate between any-to-any component, This way you can close sidebar from any component. [Stackblitz Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/example-for-arter)

//Shared Service

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable()
export class SidebarEventsService {

  closeSidebarEvent = new Subject<string>();
  closeSidebarEvent$ = this.closeSidebarEvent.asObservable();

  constructor() { }

}
```

**nav-list.component.ts**

```
***
import { SidebarEventsService } from '../../sidebar-events.service';

***
constructor(private sidebarEventsService: SidebarEventsService) {}

***
onSidenavClose = () => {
  this.sidebarEventsService.closeSidebarEvent.next();
};
```

**app.component.ts**

```
***
import { SidebarEventsService } from './sidebar-events.service';
@ViewChild("sidenav", { static: false }) sidenav; // For angular 8 only
@ViewChild('sidenav') sidenav; // will be (static: false) by default from angular 9

  constructor(private sidebarEventsService: SidebarEventsService) {
    this.sidebarEventsService.closeSidebarEvent$.subscribe(() => this.sidenav.toggle());
  }
```

Comment: Please, sry I put the wrong URL,  now I edit...please take a look

Comment: excelent... when I add `@ViewChild('sidenav') sidenav;` get error  `Expected 2 arguments, but got 1.`

Comment: In angular 8 a second parameter is required as `@ViewChild('sidenav', {static: false})` [Read more here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56359612/11719787). Happy coding :)

Comment: thank you thank you.... pls edit in ur answer  to `@ViewChild("sidenav", { static: false }) sidenav;`