# @ViewChild not working after upgrading to Angular 9

Tags: angular

After upgrading to Angular 9, basically all my `@ViewChild` references are not initialized anymore.

No matter what,

```xml
<app-menu-editor #menuEditor>
</app-menu-editor>

<div #cardBody>
  <!-- ... -->
</div>
```

```js
@ViewChild('menuEditor', {read: MenuEditorComponent}) menuEditor: MenuEditorComponent;

@ViewChild('cardBody', {read: ElementRef}) cardBody: ElementRef;
```

I keep getting exceptions telling me that e.g. `menuEditor` is `undefined`.

Any idea why this is not working anymore?

Comment: Most likely because you are accessing them in `ngOnInit` instead of `ngAfterViewInit`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try

```
@ViewChild('menuEditor', {static: true, read: MenuEditorComponent}) menuEditor: MenuEditorComponent;

@ViewChild('cardBody', {static: true, read: ElementRef}) cardBody: ElementRef;
```

Like PierreDuc said, maybe you're referring to them in the `ngOnInit`.

Comment: *Why* do they keep changing this thing? Everytime I upgrade I have to do this differently or change something to get rid of warnings.. Thanks, however. This was indeed the problem.

Comment: It was an experimental change in v8, more towards letting everyone know what it meant and it was clearly mentioned that v9 won't have these, so if you need it onInit, you will have to  `{static: true,`

Comment: @displayname if you want to upgrade your angular version, you should use the cli. This will handle all these things automatically, or give you a warning saying that you should check these places.

Comment: 2 days before I update angular with the latest version  and already using @ViewChild() but var value is undefined.

E.g.
  @ViewChild(childComponent,{static: true})_childCmpt: childComponent;
And when I print _childCmpt  on button click then getting  undefined.
I am using packages - 
  "@angular/animations": "~11.2.6",
    "@angular/cdk": "^11.2.7",
    "@angular/common": "~11.2.6",
    "@angular/compiler": "~11.2.6",
    "@angular/core": "^11.2.8",
    "@angular/forms": "~11.2.6",

Comment: Also, I agree with Stefan Falk,  When i update angular version then some feature not working. Need to modify something everytime.

Answer (score 8):

I had another scenario with angular 9 that took me two days to figure out.

My problem was that none of the solutions worked; in fact, neither ViewChild nor ViewChildren worked in ANGULAR 9.

The issue, after A LOT of investigation and NO WARNS, was that my `@ViewChild` was on an ABSTRACT CLASS that WASN'T marked as a `@Component`.

So, if you're doing something like that:

```js
export abstract class AbstractBaseComponent {
   @ViewChild('test') public testRef: TestComponent;
}

@Component({
   'selector': 'base-component'
})
export class BaseComponent extends AbstractBaseComponent {
    ngAfterViewInit() {
        console.log(this.testRef);
    }
}
```

THIS WON'T WORK.
**you must add `@Component` on the abstract class as well**:

```js
@Component({})
export abstract class AbstractBaseComponent {
   @ViewChild('test') public testRef: TestComponent;
}
```

Further reading about that can be (indirectly) found in the breaking changes in angular 9:

- https://angular.io/guide/updating-to-version-9
- https://angular.io/guide/deprecations#undecorated-base-classes

Although it's not mentioned that abstract classes follows the same behavior, it is actually intended to be as it is, since abstract classes are technically not transpiled.

Answer (score 5):

I am guessing that you are getting `undefined` either within the `ngOnInit` hook or inside of the class constructor. If my guess is correct then here's your problem:

A view child becomes available within `ngOnInit` **if** you use the `static: true` option inside the @ViewChild decorator. If `static: true` option is not set, then your view child only becomes available in `ngAfterViewInit`. The `static` options is set to [false by default](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChild).

[This SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56359612/3634032) may also be of help.

Answer (score 1):

**For Angular 8 and above, you can go for the following:**

```
 @ViewChild('txtName', {static: false}) txtName: ElementRef;
    
    { static: true } needs to be set when you want to access the ViewChild in ngOnInit.
        
    { static: false } can only be accessed in ngAfterViewInit. This is also what you want to go for when you have a structural directive (i.e. *ngIf) on your element in your template.
```