# View child in the new Angular

Tags: angular, viewchild

I'm studing Angular. How is better to configure the new Angular 8 view child?

```
@ViewChild('example', {read: ElementRef, static: false})
public example: ElementRef;
```

or

```
@ViewChild('example', {read: ElementRef, static: true})
public example: ElementRef;
```

Which is better? When should I use `static:true` vs `static:false`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How should I use the new static option for @ViewChild in Angular 8?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56359504/how-should-i-use-the-new-static-option-for-viewchild-in-angular-8)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can go for the following:

- `{ static: true }` needs to be set when you want to access the `ViewChild` in `ngOnInit`.
- `{ static: false }` can only be accessed  in `ngAfterViewInit`.

Answer (score 0):

`{ static: true }` is used to resolve query results before change detection runs,

`{ static: true }` is used to resolve after change detection.

**What is change detection in angular ?**

> Angular can detect when component data changes, and then automatically
> re-render the view to reflect that change.

Hope this could help.