# How to get access to nativeElements on ngOnInit?

Tags: javascript, angular

Suppose in my angular code i have access to a html element by `viewChild('someDiv')` or `constructor(private elem: ElementRef){}`.Whenever my angular component gets loaded i want access to that elements some property so i can store it in variable.Ex- i want to get the elements width as soon as that component gets loaded so my code is

```
@ViewChild('someDiv') someDiv: ElementRef;
someDivWidth;
ngOnInit(){
 someDivWidth = this.someDiv.nativeElement.clientWidth;
}
```

and my html code

```
<div #someDiv>some text</div>
```

But this is giving error like nativeElement is undefined.So how can i solve this?My basic need is as soon as this component loads i want to set that div's width in variable without triggering
any function.

Update:

So using `constructor(private elem: ElementRef){}` isn't giving any error and i can get access to width by

```
ngOnInit(){
 this.someDivWidth = this.elem.nativeElement.querySelector('.someCssSelector');
}
```

But suppose i have some products data which i am fetching from backend and storing in an array in ngOnInit lifecycle hook and in my template creating multiple div's depending upon the products data array using lifecycle hook.In that case if i want to get all the product div's currently i am doing like

```
products = [];
items;
ngOnInit(){
 this.productService.getProducts().subscribe(products => {
  this.products = products 
 })
 this.itmes = this.elem.nativeElement.querySelectorAll('.each-product');
 console.log(this.items)
}
```

this is giving me a empty nodeList.I thought at the time of setting this.items my products don't gets loaded from backend thats why its giving me empty array or nodeList but putting that last two lines in subscribe() like

```
ngOnInit(){
 this.productService.getProducts().subscribe(products => {
  this.products = products 
  this.itmes = this.elem.nativeElement.querySelectorAll('.each-product');
  console.log(this.items)
 })
}
```

and my html code is

```
<div>
 <div *ngFor='let product of products' class='each-product'>...</div>
</div>
```

is still giving me an empty array or nodelist.What to do??

Comment: ViewChild is only accesible after ngAfterViewInit. if you want to acces in ngOnInit use `{static:true}`:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56359504/how-should-i-use-the-new-static-option-for-viewchild-in-angular-8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Angular uses its algorithms to detect changes in data and respond to the view. If you want to opreate the DOM after the request was completed, you may not be able to get it because the view hasn't been updated yet, and you can understand that Angular also needs time to update the view.
Offer two solutions

1. Use `ChangeDetectorRef` to perform change detection manually
2. use `setTimeout`

[stackblitz-demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-jtgss6?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: Why i am still getting empty nodelist using ngAfterViewInit.Html code `<div class="slideshow-card" *ngFor="let product of products">

      </div>` and ts code `ngAfterViewInit() {
    console.log(this.elem.nativeElement.querySelectorAll('.slideshow-card'));
  }`

Comment: I have updated the code above. You need to learn about async request and lifestyle of Angular.

Comment: You need to make sure that the DOM is rendered by the end of the your request

Comment: Is that code works for you??Because  i am still getting empty nodeList after calling the backend in ngAfterViewInit and console loging the querySelectorAll() in the subscribe method.

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-czs5mo?file=src/app/app.component.css  ..check in the code if i don't callback the backend in both ngOnInit and ngAfterViewInit i am getting empty nodelist hence totalWidth is 0.In first ngOnInit i am calling backend and subscribing to it to set my items array and in ngAfterViewInit if i am working with the items related dom without calling and subscribing to the backend again i am getting empty nodelist..do i have to call the backend and subscribe both in ngOnInit and ngAfterViewInit??

Answer (score 3):

You should do it in the ngAfterViewInit method of the angular life cycle.

```
 ngAfterViewInit(){
             this.someDivWidth = this.elem.nativeElement.querySelector('.someCssSelector');
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

`ngOnInit` lifeCycle is invoked **once** when component **instantiated** and called right after the properties checked for the first time, and before its children checked.

If You want to be sure that view has been loaded `(@ViewChild` depends on view to be rendered) you should use `ngAfterViewInit` which is called after component view and it's children view are created and ready.

**UPDATE**: If you need to access `viewChild` in `ngOnInit` you have to set `{ static: true }`

Comment: Ok i understanded that part but can you please tell me why i am getting an empty nodelist here in `this.itmes = this.elem.nativeElement.querySelectorAll('.each-product');` and what to do for solving that problem??