# Angular 'nativeElement + viewchild' vs 'document.querySelector' is quite confusing

Tags: angular, viewchild, queryselector

I have this component:

```
<div #widget
     class="widget">
</div> 

@ViewChild('widget') widget!: any;

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log(this.widget.nativeElement) //returns undedined
  }
```

However it is working if I use native api:

```
console.log(document.querySelector('.widget'));
```

Then I've done some research and figure out that:

```
  @ViewChild('widget', {static: true}) widget!: any;
```

It is fixed the native element looking to the answers to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56359612), however the [main answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56359612/415078) there is quite confusing:

> In most cases you will want to use {static: false}. Setting it like
> this will ensure query matches that are dependent on binding
> resolution (like structural directives *ngIf, etc...) will be found.

and

> The { static: true } option was introduced to support creating
> embedded views on the fly. When you are creating a view dynamically
> and want to acces the TemplateRef, you won't be able to do so in
> ngAfterViewInit as it will cause a ExpressionHasChangedAfterChecked
> error. Setting the static flag to true will create your view in
> ngOnInit.

So now I do have a few questions

1. Does it mean that `@ViewChild('widget', {static: true}) widget!` is equal to `document.querySelector('.widget')`?
2. Is they are not equal in what cases I have to use `@ViewChild('widget', {static: true}) widget!` vs `document.querySelector('.widget')`?
3. In what cases i should use `@ViewChild('widget', {static: true}) widget!` vs `@ViewChild('widget', {static: false}) widget!`?
4. In my case I am not using any dynamic views but the refered [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56359612/415078) suggesting to use `{static: false}` is quite bizarre.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. About `{static:true}` vs `{static:false}`.

   If your "div" is not under a *ngIf -it's always visible- you can
   indicate to Angular not "check" if exist or not each time else check
   only one time at very first stage of the component. For this you use
   `{static:true}`. In this way you can access so early as in ngOnInit
2. About `document.querySelector('.widget')` vs `@ViewChild`

   Really a ViewChild you get a ElementRef (is in the property
   nativeElement where you get the "HTML element"). So with ViewChild
   you can access not only to the "HTML element", else, if is a
   component, to the component, if the tag has a directive to the
   directive.... Really you get a "reference" to any component or
   directive or HTML element.

   If you only has a simple tag (a div, a H1, a p, ...) the "Angular
   way" is also use ViewChild to insolate or encapsulate and not depend
   of if is executed in a navigator o not (really you get a reference
   to the DOM, some like `<div ng_content-1 ....>`), but as you can do
   the same with using reference.nativeElement and the document.querySelector really it's not much diference

Comment: so yeah in simple cases where you do not really need a power of framework you can just use querySelector, right?

Comment: @sreginogemoh, yes. But really should be a few cases you need use it. e.g. if we want to add a class to a div, it's better use a variable `<div [class.custom]="variable">` instead of ask about document.querySelector to add a class. (idem if you want to add an event). In general we should "think in variables" and "binding" properties better than manipulate the DOM directly.

Answer (score 0):

You have can only access you widget after the view is initialized.

So,  instead accessing it on `ngOnInit()` hook, you can access it on `ngAfterViewInit()`.

```
export class AddUpdateFormComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  @ViewChild('widget') widget!: any;

  ngAfterViewInit() : void {
    console.log(this.widget.nativeElement)
  }

}
```

Comment: really not. If your "div" is not under a *ngIf, you can get it in ngOnInit if you use `{static:true}`

Comment: @Eliseo that is what I do